# Stored Procedure unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having a little trouble with a large bit of coding in this Stored procedure. i have it working to the point that it prints the letters to every customer in the table but i need it to be state sensitive so that when entered into the procedure it returns only those customers. i tried altering the while clause but i am having some unexpected results with it erasing the name of the customers.

```
Create Proc spNewsLetter
@StateID varchar(2)
as



DECLARE @CustCount INT
DECLARE @CustomerName varchar(10)
DECLARE @LastName varchar(20)
DECLARE @FirstName varchar(15) 
DECLARE @SalesOfficer varchar(20)
DECLARE @Date as varchar(12) 
DECLARE @FutureDate as varChar(12)
DECLARE @JobDescription as varchar (20)

SET @CustomerName = '       '

Set @futureDate = DATEADD(dd, 14, getdate())

SET @Date = convert(char(12),getDate(), 107)

SELECT @SalesOfficer = FirstName + ' ' + LastName, @JobDescription = JobTitle
FROM Employee WHERE JobTitle = 'Chief Sales Officer'

SELECT @CustCount = count(*) FROM Customer  

SELECT @StateID = State
FROM Customer

IF EXISTS (Select @StateID from Customer)
BEGIN
WHILE @CustCount > 0  
BEGIN

 SELECT @CustomerName = MIN(CustomerID)
   FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID > @CustomerName
 SELECT @LastName = CustLastName,
   @FirstName=CustFirstName 
   FROM Customer WHERE  CustomerID = @CustomerName
 PRINT ' '
 PRINT ' '
 PRINT ' '
 PRINT ' '
 PRINT ' Date:' + @Date  
 PRINT ' '               
 PRINT ' Dear ' + @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName + ','
 PRINT ' '
 PRINT ' Eagle is please to offer you a 20% discount on any purchase you make prior   to 11:55pm '+@FutureDate+'.'                 
 PRINT ' This limited time offer is our best offer of the year!  You can view our entire product line '
 PRINT ' and place your order at Eagle20Deal.com.  Make sure to place your order by ' +@FutureDate
 PRINT ' because this offer expires at 11:55pm on that day.'
 PRINT ' '
 PRINT ' Sincerely, ' + @SalesOfficer 
 PRINT '            '+@JobDescription           
 PRINT '            Eagle Corporation' 
 PRINT '*****************************************' 

 SET @CustCount = @CustCount - 1 

END  -- *** end of while block
END -- *** end of if
ELSE 
BEGIN
 Print 'Please enter a valid state ID'
END  -- *** end of else block
```

any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: If @StateID is passed into the procedure then why are you selecting a value into it?

Comment: could you elaborate on that a bit? i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: DO you mean for me to remove the select statement involving @stateID

Comment: Your procedure accepts a value for StateID.  You then do     SELECT @StateID = State FROM Customer.  This then replaces the value in the StateID variable with the value from Customer.  Side note: I am betting you get an error on that line since I bet Customer has more than one row.

Comment: i am actually not receiving any errors at the moments. Dont i need to ascociate @StateID with a value from the customers table?

Comment: OK i have figured out where a large part of my trouble was coming from

Comment: OK i have figured out where a large part of my trouble was coming from.Now where i am having issues is how do i get the WHILE to print each individuals name instead of repeatedly print the same name over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I figured our the problem your comments did help some  later on in the program thank you here is the finished product

```
Create Proc spNewsLetter
@StateID varchar(2)
as

DECLARE @CustCount varchar (20)
DECLARE @CustomerName varchar(10)
DECLARE @LastName varchar(20)
DECLARE @FirstName varchar(15) 
DECLARE @SalesOfficer varchar(20)
DECLARE @Date as varchar(12) 
DECLARE @FutureDate as varChar(12)
DECLARE @JobDescription as varchar (20)
DECLARE @CompanyName Varchar(20)


SET @CustomerName = '       '

Set @futureDate = DATEADD(dd, 14, getdate())


SET @Date = convert(char(12),getDate(), 107)

SELECT @SalesOfficer = FirstName + ' ' + LastName, @JobDescription = JobTitle
FROM Employee WHERE JobTitle = 'Chief Sales Officer'

SELECT @CustCount = Count(CustomerID) FROM Customer  
WHERE @StateID = State


if @CustCount > 0   
BEGIN
 WHILE @CustCount > 0   
   BEGIN

     SELECT @CustomerName = MIN(CustomerID)
       FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID > @CustomerName and @StateID = State
     SELECT @LastName = CustLastName,
       @FirstName=CustFirstName, @CompanyName = Coalesce(CompanyName,'')
       FROM Customer WHERE  CustomerID = @CustomerName and @StateID = State
     PRINT ' '
     PRINT ' '
     PRINT ' '
     PRINT ' '
     PRINT ' Date:' + @Date  
     PRINT ' '               
     PRINT ' Dear ' + @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName + ', '+@CompanyName 
     PRINT ' '
     PRINT ' Eagle is please to offer you a 20% discount on any purchase you make prior to 11:55pm '+@FutureDate+'.'
     PRINT ' This limited time offer is our best offer of the year!  You can view our entire product line '
     PRINT ' and place your order at Eagle20Deal.com.  Make sure to place your order by ' +@FutureDate
     PRINT ' because this offer expires at 11:55pm on that day.'
     PRINT ' '
     PRINT ' Sincerely, ' + @SalesOfficer 
     PRINT '            '+@JobDescription           
     PRINT '            Eagle Corporation' 
     PRINT '*****************************************' 

     SET @CustCount = @CustCount - 1 


   END
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
     Print 'Please enter a valid state ID'
END
```

Comment: Glad you got it.  Just a couple of comments.  You don't need the IF around the loop.  If @CustCount is 0 then the loop won't start.  You also should look into Cursors (I can't believe I just said that).  Most of this work should be done in the application/report level and not in the database.  But if you have to do it here then maybe this would be a decent place for a Cursor.  It allows you to retrieve all the rows once and then loop through them.